# Подключение статических библиотек в MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, codeblocks

Итак, некоторая есть статическая библиотека - в данном случае libantlr4-runtime.a. Я пытаюсь подключить её к своему проекту в CodeBlocks. И вот тут возникла нечаянность, с которой я никак не могу справиться.
Сама библиотека выглядит вполне ординарно. Содержит внутри себя функции - например, такую

__ZN6antlr416ANTLRInputStreamC1ERSi

Эта функция вызывается в одном из файлов проекта, подключающего обсуждаемую библиотеку. Вызывается следующим образом:

ANTLRInputStream input(in);

то есть эта функция - конструктор объекта ANTLRInputStream.
И вот при компиляции проекта валом валят такого рода ошибки:

C:\CodeBlocksProjects\ElectronicSheetFrontend\FormulaAST.cpp|440|undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6antlr416ANTLRInputStreamC1ERSi'

То есть компилятор в месте вызова упомянутой функции пытается вместо неё вызвать другую:
_imp___ZN6antlr416ANTLRInputStreamC1ERSi.

То есть на самом деле как раз ту самую, нужную функцию, но только её имя почему-то отличается от правильного оригинала добавлением к нему префикса *imp*. И так происходит со всеми вызовами функций этой библиотеки (там их около сотни, здесь приведена только одна). Почему-то при создании библиотеки и при вызове функций меняются правила декорировки C++-имён и при вызове компилятор зачем-то добавляет к именам эту приставку *imp*_. Что же это такое и как с этим бороться?

Comment: Imho, компилятор пытается вызвать функцию из динамической библиотеки.

Comment: Везде, где только можно, передаю компилятору параметр -static. И ничего не меняется. Что же можно предпринять ещё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Объясняю ход мыслей:

- Ищем, где объявлен `ANTLRInputStream`. У меня это `/mingw64/include/antlr4-runtime/ANTLRInputStream.h`.
- Конструкторы выглядят так:

  ```
  ANTLRInputStream(const std::string &input);
  ANTLRInputStream(const char *data, size_t length);
  ANTLRInputStream(std::istream &stream);
  ```

  Пока ничего необычного.
- Сам класс объявлен так: `class ANTLR4CPP_PUBLIC ANTLRInputStream`. Это уже интереснее.
- Ищем, что такое `ANTLR4CPP_PUBLIC`. Находим `/mingw64/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-common.h` и в нем вот это:

  ```
  #ifdef ANTLR4CPP_EXPORTS
    #define ANTLR4CPP_PUBLIC __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #ifdef ANTLR4CPP_STATIC
      #define ANTLR4CPP_PUBLIC
    #else
      #define ANTLR4CPP_PUBLIC __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
  #endif
  ```
- `ANTLR4CPP_STATIC` звучит многообещающе. Добавляем флаг `-DANTLR4CPP_STATIC`, чтобы задефайнить его. (В дополнение к `-static`.)
- Все работает.

Comment: Ура!!! Чёрт побери, всё действительно работает. От котов, оказывается, тоже есть польза для программирования. Особенно от чёрных. Огромное спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @dichrograph Пожалуйста. :) Тыкните галочку слева, чтобы отметить вопрос как решенный.